# Where is /tf messages generated in DRCSIM?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I do

```
roslaunch atlas_utils atlas.launch
```

and

```
rostopic list
```

I see /tf messages. Can someone point me to where in gazebo land (source code) is tf messages generated for atlas? Many thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2003/where-is-/tf-messages-generated-in-drcsim?/) by [sfeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/277/sfeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

tf is generated outside gazebo using the robot_state_publisher(s) (One for the robot, one for the multisense head). Gazebo publishes joint states of the robot. The robot_state_publisher nodes receive those, generate the tf transforms based on them and publish them to tf.
By running

```
rxgraph
```

You can look at the computation graph and see the topic connections between gazebo, robot_state_publisher and all other nodes.

See also the [robot_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher) wiki page.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 473 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1